# HTML attribute names are case-sensitive? Conflicting information.

Tags: html, css

I just read that attribute names are case-sensitive:

> Attribute names are also case-sensitive, for example the two width
>   attributes in  and  (if they
>   occurred in the same file) are separate attributes, because of the
>   different case of width and WIDTH;

(http://xml.silmaril.ie/case.html)

But then I went on JSFiddle to try

HTML

```
<p ID="myId">Let's see if this is red</p>
```

CSS

```
#myId {color: red;}
```

and, indeed, the text was red: http://jsfiddle.net/xtLr08u7/.

Which is correct?

Comment: That's an XML resource, not an HTML resource. Both are very similar, but live by very different rules.

Answer (score 4):

Attribute names are not case sensitive in neither HTML 4 nor in HTML5, as the [W3C HTML Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#case-insensitivity) says.

But XHTML (HTML with XML syntax) is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

They means for custom attributes only. The normal attributes are not case-sensitive.

Such as `<tag myAttr="myattr" MyAttr="MYATTR"></tag>` (refers to XML not HTML)